# Cron not working properly from c panel but from url working as expected

Tags: php, cron, magento-1.8

I have setup cron job, it is working properly,when i directly runs the php file(from the path/url) it successfully runs, but from cron its not. i have used simple php mail function and its is running successfully but my task is not completed properly. Kindly suggest me the possible areas to look into it. (I am using Cpanel). here this is the code that i am using in cron.ch

```
#!/bin/sh
# location of the php binary
if [ ! "$1" = "" ] ; then
CRONSCRIPT=$1
else
CRONSCRIPT=cron.php
fi

PHP_BIN=`which php`

# absolute path to magento installation
INSTALLDIR=`echo $0 | sed 's/cron\.sh//g'`

#   prepend the intallation path if not given an absolute path
if [ "$INSTALLDIR" != "" -a "`expr index $CRONSCRIPT /`" != "1" ];then
    if ! ps auxwww | grep "$INSTALLDIR""$CRONSCRIPT" | grep -v grep 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
    $PHP_BIN "$INSTALLDIR""$CRONSCRIPT" &
    fi
else
    if  ! ps auxwww | grep " $CRONSCRIPT" | grep -v grep | grep -v cron.sh 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $CRONSCRIPT &
    fi
fi
```

this is how i am setting cron for every 15 minutes from c-panel

```
*/15    *   *   *   *
```

Comment: try to debug the script by writing some demo content in text file and make sure you cron is working or not or where execution stopping.

Comment: `PHP_BIN='which php'` -- may not return you a path to the PHP binary if your PATH environment variable is not properly set up. A high percentage of problems with cron scripts arise from this issue. I would hardcode the path to the PHP binary.